# Trying unsuccessfully to import scapy after installed with pip

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pip, scapy, winpcap

***Summarizing the problem :***

> By trying to do "from scapy.all import *" I got the following error :
>
> [image]

Hi,

I'm trying to do project with scapy, but unfortuently I had a porblem so I decided to delete my python and pycharm and install everything again. This didn't work too and after installing him with pip and trying to run, I got the error above...

someone know what to do? I'm desperate :(

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in January: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1819

You should try using the github dev version. Here's the doc on how to use it: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#current-development-version